# How do you check if a certain index exists in a table?

Tags: sql-server

Something like this:

```
SELECT
* 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME ='FK_TreeNodesBinaryAssets_BinaryAssets'
and TABLE_NAME = 'TreeNodesBinaryAssets'
```

but for indexes.

Comment: I wish INFORMATION_SCHEMA actually had all the schema information

Answer (score 599, accepted):

You can do it using a straight forward select like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.indexes 
WHERE name='YourIndexName' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('Schema.YourTableName')
```

Comment: You can also wrap the statement into a `IF EXISTS(SELECT * ...) BEGIN ... END`.

Comment: It's worth to mention that `YourTableName` should be full name with schema

Comment: I used your query without the name='YourIndexName' clause and noted the name of a unique constraint on my table from the name column returned by your query. Its like UNIQ_.... I get an error - is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint. See previous errors. How do I fix this ?

Comment: @Marek - I did it without mentioning dbo schema. It works. Why do we need to have a schema ?

Comment: @blasto If you use non-default schema, like in most of my cases, specifying schema as prefix is mandatory. In other case, you wont get any results in this query

Comment: To check against a temp table, can use 'tempdb.sys.indexes' and 'tempdb..#TableName'.  (ref [Bjorn D. Jensen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dbee7c2d-b2be-41d9-bd59-f2025c898483/existence-of-index-for-temp-table))

Comment: Just to add: "Beginning with SQL Server 2016 you can use the DROP INDEX IF EXISTS syntax." [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-index-transact-sql)

Comment: you could use `SCHEMA_NAME ( )  ` to get current schema

Comment: @heringer Why they didn't add a parallel `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS` command, I can't imagine :(

Answer (score 147):

For **SQL 2008 and newer**, a more concise method, coding-wise, to detect index existence is by using the [`INDEXPROPERTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/indexproperty-transact-sql) built-in function:

```
INDEXPROPERTY ( object_ID , index_or_statistics_name , property )
```

The simplest usage is with the `IndexID` property:

```
If IndexProperty(Object_Id('MyTable'), 'MyIndex', 'IndexID') Is Null
```

If the index exists, the above will return its ID; if it doesn't, it will return `NULL`.

Answer (score 87):

AdaTheDEV,  I used your syntax and created the following and why.

Problem: Process runs once a quarter taking an hour due to missing index.

Correction: Alter query process or Procedure to check for index and create it if missing... Same code is placed at the end of the query and procedure to remove index since it is not needed but quarterly. Showing Only drop syntax here

```
-- drop the index 
begin

  IF EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM sys.indexes  WHERE name='Index_Name' 
    AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('[SchmaName].[TableName]'))
  begin
    DROP INDEX [Index_Name] ON [SchmaName].[TableName];
  end

end
```

Answer (score 44):

If the hidden purpose of your question is to `DROP` the index before making `INSERT` to a large table, then this is useful one-liner:

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS [IndexName] ON [dbo].[TableName]
```

This syntax is available since SQL Server 2016. Documentation for `IF EXISTS`:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/11/03/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016/

In case you deal with a primery key instead, then use this:

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS [PK_name]
```

Comment: Not working for SQL Server 2014. Works for SQL Server 2019

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

A slight deviation from the original question however may prove useful for future people landing here wanting to `DROP` and `CREATE` an index, i.e. in a deployment script.

You can bypass the exists check simply by adding the following to your create statement:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_IndexName
ON dbo.TableName
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

Read more here: [CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL) - DROP_EXISTING Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx#DROP_EXISTING%20Clause)

N.B. As mentioned in the comments, the index must already exist for this clause to work without throwing an error.

Comment: Actually.. be careful! This will fail if the index doesn't already exist! At least in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: ...and it still fails in SQL 2016

Comment: Another (maybe obvious) effect is that it will alway re-create the index.  This may not be what you want.  Dropping and Creating an index on a large table is an expensive operation - esp if the existing index is already the one you want.  This statement is good for one-step replacement.   It doesn't compare the existing index - rather a brute force "do this, even if existing - drop it...just do it, get'r done!"  :-)      It still requires all of the checking that OP was looking for. However, if the index needs replacing it combines the DROP/CREATE.

Comment: Also, it fails in SQL Server 2022 if index does not exist. But IMHO it very strange effect. Why MS did it?...

Answer (score 7):

Wrote the below function that allows me to quickly check to see if an index exists; works just like OBJECT_ID.

```
CREATE FUNCTION INDEX_OBJECT_ID (
    @tableName VARCHAR(128),
    @indexName VARCHAR(128)
    )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @objectId INT

    SELECT @objectId = i.object_id
    FROM sys.indexes i
    WHERE i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)
    AND i.name = @indexName

    RETURN @objectId
END
GO
```

EDIT: This just returns the OBJECT_ID of the table, but it will be NULL if the index doesn't exist.  I suppose you could set this to return index_id, but that isn't super useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
-- Delete index if exists
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.indexes indexes INNER JOIN sys.objects 
objects ON indexes.object_id = objects.object_id WHERE indexes.name 
='Your_Index_Name' AND objects.name = 'Your_Table_Name')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'DROP INDEX [Your_Index_Name] ON [dbo].[Your_Table_Name]'
    DROP INDEX [our_Index_Name] ON [dbo].[Your_Table_Name]
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC sp_helpindex '[[[SCHEMA-NAME.TABLE-NAME]]]'
GO
```

Comment: more correct: EXEC sp_helpindex '[SCHEMA-NAME].[TABLE-NAME]'. This will return all indexes that exist in the table. More information - "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helpindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16"

Answer (score -1):

To check Clustered Index exist on particular table or not:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.indexes 
WHERE index_id = 1 AND name IN (SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table_Name')
```

Comment: This returns primary keys and unique constraints, but none of those is necessarily a clustered index.

Comment: index_id = 1 is incorrect where clause.  The index may be assigned a different id