# How do I check if a nonclustered index exists in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, non-clustered-index

I have the following:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MyTableIndex]
ON [dbo].[tablename] ([tablename_ID],[tablename_Field1])
INCLUDE ([Tablename_Field2],[Tablename_Field3])
```

I want to create an if statement to check if this exists. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689766/how-do-you-check-if-a-certain-index-exists-in-a-table

Answer (score 215, accepted):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'MyTableIndex' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('tablename'))
    BEGIN
        -- Index with this name, on this table does NOT exist
    END
```

Comment: +1 This is working nice. Should or not be concerned about the table schema?

Comment: @gotqn - to take schema into account, you can just include it as a two part name in the OBJECT_ID call e.g. OBJECT_ID('myschema.tablename')

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE Name = 'MyTableIndex')
   -- put your CREATE INDEX statement here
```

Comment: I advise also checking object_id (as per AdaTheDev's answer) as index names aren't unique.