# How do you check if a certain index exists for a table in another schema?

Tags: sql-server

Inspired from this SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689766/how-do-you-check-if-a-certain-index-exists-in-a-table)

I created this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dropIndexWithSchema](@schemaName VARCHAR(200), @tableName VARCHAR(200), @indexName VARCHAR(200))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(512)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT i.* FROM @schemaName.sys.indexes i WHERE i.name = @indexName AND i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@schemaName + '.dbo.' + @tableName))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = 'DROP INDEX ' + @indexName + ' ON ' + @schemaName + '.dbo.' + @tableName;
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    END
END
GO
```

Of course this doesn't work as `@schemaName` in the FROM clause is not able to be parametrised. Also there is the problem of constructing the object name for the `OBJECT_ID` function.

I want to write a procedure that will, from schema A, to be able to drop an index on a table in schema B, if it exists.

Comment: There's no such thing as `<schemaname>.sys.indexes`. It's `<database>.sys.indexes`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll note it for the future. I find it confusing when talking about similar concepts across the various database offerings.

Comment: The schema is the `dbo` part of the query. You might have multiple `IX_Test` on `dbo.instruments` and `dbo2.instruments` in different schemas on the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dropIndexWithSchema](@schemaName VARCHAR(200), @tableName VARCHAR(200), @indexName VARCHAR(200))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(512)
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT i.* FROM ' + @schemaName+'.sys.indexes i WHERE i.name = '''+@indexName+''' AND i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('''+@schemaName + '.dbo.' + @tableName+''')'
    EXEC sp_executesql @query
    IF (@@rowcount > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = 'DROP INDEX ' + @indexName + ' ON ' + @schemaName + '.dbo.' + @tableName;
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It looks very promising. I'll check back later and report if it does exactly what I want.

Comment: it seems to, when I tested it

Comment: Thanks @FuzzyJulz. This did it. I tweaked my solution to further to suit my situation but you helped a lot.