# Drop indexes or alter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to drop pk constraint and drop index on the target table in informatica, these below statements are working first time successfully.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM sysindexes WHERE Name = 'xyz') 
DROP INDEX [xyz] ON [dbo].[Table_Name];

IF EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM sysindexes WHERE Name = 'xyz')
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name] DROP CONSTRAINT [xyz];
```

But if I run the same query a second time it is giving an error:

> Cannot drop the index 'dbo.Table_Name.xyz', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

I need an `If ... Else` statement syntax like if exists drop else end or success something.

Comment: The parser is seeing you try to drop an index that doesn't exist, but not smart enough to follow your IF logic. Use dynamic SQL (`IF EXISTS (...) EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'DROP INDEX ...';`). Also, use `sys.indexes` rather than the deprecated `sysindexes`, and make sure you identify that the index belongs to that table (there could also be an index named `xyz` on another table).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2689766/12484

Answer (score 11):

The likely cause for this is that you might have more than one index named `xyz` on your database.  Your `IF EXISTS` `SELECT` statement is not taking into consideration *which* table `xyz` is on.

You can check for this condition yourself by running the select statement by itself.

Try changing your query to the following to limit the scope:

```
If Exists 
(
    Select * 
    From   sys.indexes 
    Where  name = 'xyz' 
    And    Object_Id = Object_Id('dbo.Table_Name')
)
Drop Index xyz On dbo.Table_Name;
```

Comment: No, while this is technically better, it doesn't solve the chicken and egg issue caused by a not-very-intelligent parser.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  ... Or the lack of syntax for "drop if exists" ;).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I disagree.  If he has two indexes in the same database that are named the same thing, his `IF EXISTS` statement would still come back as true.  *Then* it would try to drop the index on `Table_Name`.  Without including the table in the `EXISTS` statement, with two indexes named the same thing, he would get that error.  I suspect that's what's happening here.

Comment: Hey siyual, the above command is working for me, sorry my bad there are more than 2 indexes but with different name, but when i posted the question, i used the same index name, but my purpose if doesn't exist still it is succeeding. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: There are many cases where this will be a compilation error, rather than a runtime error, so generally, a better defensive practice is to move DLL commands that will potentially be repeated to a different scope (even if, in *some* scenarios, it works as expected).

Comment: @Gordon in 2016 you can say `DROP INDEX IF EXISTS xyz ON dbo.abc;`

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . Yeah!

Answer (score 2):

One way to get around this issue is to trick the parser:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table_Name' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'xyz')
BEGIN
    EXEC('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name] DROP CONSTRAINT [xyz]')
END
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't really work, because (1) there can't be two primary keys named xyz in the database, and (2) the `OBJECT_ID` function could be identifying a pk on a different table, in which case the `EXEC()` will still run.

Comment: (1) What's your point? (2) Have you ever tried putting two identically named PKs in the same database? There can't be two, because SQL Server won't let you name two PKs the same thing, even if they are on different tables.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the pks are not named same but in the above i used it s as an example, i have more than one pk with different names.

Comment: (1) My point is that using PK as the object type isn't very useful (the OP doesn't have a PK). (2) Of course, that's why I said what I said.

Comment: My main point, though, is that if you use things like `OBJECT_ID` to identify if something exists, you can't be certain it exists on the right table. For example, create this table: `CREATE TABLE dbo.OtherTable(id int, CONSTRAINT xyz PRIMARY KEY(id));` Now run your code. The `EXEC()` still runs because the `OBJECT_ID()` returned a valid value, but fails because it is from a different table.

Comment: I see your point now. I've corrected the `IF` statement. The point of the answer though, is that using `EXEC` with a string will get around the parser issue.

Comment: Yeah, [that sounds familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398467/drop-indexes-or-alter/37399042#comment62305937_37398467). :-)

Comment: Didn't read your comment when I posted the answer. Turn the comment into an answer and I'll delete this one.